# What triggers rebuild of webpack-bundle in HMR with SpaServices?

Tags: c#, webpack, asp.net-core, asp-net-core-spa-services

I'm using ASP.Net Core with Typescript/React/SpaServices/Webpack/HMR.
When changing a tsx file HMR replaces the code in the browser.

My question in what function/program is watching the files for changes and then triggers the rebuild? Is webpack running in the background using node? If so, can I see that process running? Logs etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is webpack running in the background using node?

Yes, absolutely. There's a lot going on here, but ultimately both `webpack` and the `webpack-dev-middleware` are handling this.

It starts with the call to `UseWebpackDevMiddleware`. e.g.:

```
app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
{
    HotModuleReplacement = true
});
```

As I've already said, there's a lot going on behind the scenes here, so I'll just give an overview of the main parts at play. Here's an important line of code from  `UseWebpackDevMiddleware` ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/release/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices/Webpack/WebpackDevMiddleware.cs#L89)):

```
nodeServices.InvokeExportAsync<WebpackDevServerInfo>(
    nodeScript.FileName,
    "createWebpackDevServer",
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(devServerOptions)).Result;
```

The `InvokeExortAsync` function is where the communication between ASP.NET Core and NodeJs occurs. The `nodeServices` variable is an instance of `HttpNodeInstance`, which is a child of `OutOfProcessNodeInstance`. The `OutOfProcessNodeInstance` class spawns a NodeJs server when it's constructed, like so ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/release/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices/HostingModels/OutOfProcessNodeInstance.cs#L78)):

```
_nodeProcess = LaunchNodeProcess(startInfo);
```

This ends up running a NodeJs server using the entrypoint-http.js script file ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/release/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices/Content/Node/entrypoint-http.js)). This has a lot of code, but it ends up creating a HTTP server that listens for requests that come out of calls to `InvokeExportAsync`.

The JavaScript function that is being invoked here, `createWebpackDevServer` ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/release/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices/TypeScript/WebpackDevMiddleware.ts)), looks like this, with exception-handling removed for brevity:

```js
export function createWebpackDevServer(callback) {
    let aspNetWebpack = require('aspnet-webpack');
    return aspNetWebpack.createWebpackDevServer.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

There's a lot of code for the `createWebpackDevServer` that is being *invoked* ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/release/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices/npm/aspnet-webpack/src/WebpackDevMiddleware.ts#L216)), so I won't include it here, but suffice to say it ends up running a connect server ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/release/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices/npm/aspnet-webpack/src/WebpackDevMiddleware.ts#L241)) that uses the webpack-dev-middleware ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/release/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices/npm/aspnet-webpack/src/WebpackDevMiddleware.ts#L109)).

I hope that gives enough of an explanation and a starting point for your own exploration.

Answer (score 0):

- **The component’s state changes :** A re-render can only be triggered if a component’s state has changed. The state can change from a props change, or from a direct setState change. The component gets the updated state and decides if it should re-render the component.
- **shouldComponentUpdate method :** By default, shouldComponentUpdate returns true. That’s what causes the update everything all the time.

Comment: I'm not asking about react.